# How to create a Nameserver for my VPS (unmanaged)

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, vps, ovh

I have purchsed a OVH (IaaS, Centos 7) VPS server. I have installed apache and php. But I have very little knowledge about server. How can I create custom name server for my VPS ? any centos command ? I want to bind name server ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com with my VPS. what is the procedure ? plz help

Comment: We come here to get answer of the questions that we don't know or not found. If you think, I am doing any wrong, you shoud give a comment before holding .. Its not a bank transaction.

Comment: Please read our [help]. We close questions that are not fit for our site but they don't get deleted immediately to give you a chance to improve the question. Note the sentence `If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.`. However, this question is likely never a good fit here. [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

> But I have very little knowledge about server.

and creating a name server are not compatible. Getting DNS right is quite complicated and really a waste of time as you get a large number of providers that do that for you for a few dollars a year.